# How do I deploy app visibility settings from profiles in a sandbox to a production org?

Tags: salesforce

I have changed the visibility of an app for user Profiles in my sandbox org and I'd like to deploy those changes to the production org. I can't find a way to do that but know that I must be missing something. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Are you using profiles (old style) or permission sets? Either way, you should be able to move them via changesets.

Comment: Profiles (the old style) don't seem to move with change sets (as far as I can figure out). The metadata doesn't include anything about App visibility. I haven't looked into permission sets - I'll do that next.

Comment: Would be useful to know, at this juncture, how to transport just a profile i.e. from Production to a SandBox. (Edit: Apparently not: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005400&language=en_US)

Answer (score 4):

You can use change sets for this.  For any component you deploy you can choose to also deploy the profile permissions for some or all profiles.  Note that only the permissions related to components in the change set are deployed.  Also note that you'll get errors if you include the profile settings for a profile that exists in your sandbox, but not in your production org.

- setup->deploy->outbound change set
- name the change set, click save
- under change set components add the app to the change set
- under profile settings add any profiles you'd like to have the permissions updated for

Currently change sets don't support standard applications. However, this can be done with the Metadata API, which added the ability to retrieve Standard applications with v29. You can use the list metadata api call to retrieve the names of Standard application which are generally in the form `standard__<AppName>`, e.g. `standard__Sales`. If you retrieve the app along with the profile you're changing the permissions on, you can then deploy those settings. Do note, that this would also deploy any changes to that app in the source org and any general profile permissions (i.e. loginIpRanges, API Enabled, etc).

Sample package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>standard__Sales</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>MyProfile</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

Sample retrieved profile xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__Sales</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
    <loginIpRanges>
        <endAddress>255.255.255.255</endAddress>
        <startAddress>0.0.0.0</startAddress>
    </loginIpRanges>
    <userLicense>Salesforce</userLicense>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ActivateContract</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ApiEnabled</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <!-- truncated for brevity -->
</Profile>
```

Comment: Ralph, this appears to only work with custom applications. Do you know if it is possible to deploy the visibility of a standard application, such as Sales?

Comment: @SwisherSweet good question, it's possible with the metadata api, but not with changes sets, updated the answer with details

Comment: Thanks for the XML! knew exactly where to put it, but the exact spelling/formatting.  ah, force-scratch-only fun...